# How to synchronize loop in java so I could increment loop value manually (when some execution is complete)

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop, synchronous

I have a simple scenario.

I want to make calls to a async method (probably an api call) inside loop. I want to call the same api multiple times but don't execute the next api call until previous one is complete.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   apicall{
      apiresult
   }
}
```

The above method will run the loop 10 times normally without waiting for the api call method to be finished. what I want to do is call the next api after previous one is complete.

For example :-

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   apicall{
      apiresult
     // RUN NEXT LOOP AFTER THIS IS COMPLETE
   }
}
```

I tried using `while` loop but it was too slow and not reliable.

Comment: You can perform this task using Livedata instead of using for loop

Answer (score 2):

You could use recursion. Something along these lines:

```
void makeAPICalls(int numberOfCalls) {
    numberOfCalls--;
    if (numberOfCalls > 0) {
        apiCall {
            apiResult
            // when result arrives call this again
            makeAPICalls(numberOfCalls)
        }
    }
}
```

You would then call the function like this: `makeAPICalls(10)`